# Trackpad gestures stop working

Tags: macos, magic-trackpad

From time to time, my Magic Trackpad gestures will stop working. I can restart to bring them back, but this is pretty disruptive.

Is there a process I can kill to bring them back?

(I've tried turning off the Magic Trackpad; unfortunately, it doesn't fix the problem.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If resetting the necessary prefs does not help but the Magic Trackpad is *still connected*, this is a beautiful alternative: **BetterTouchTool**

In fact, this is much more fun since it makes the Magic Trackpad so powerful.

http://www.boastr.de/

[image]

Answer (score 8):

In 10.8, running `killall Dock` seems to bring back trackpad gestures.

When a reboot didn't fix this, I went to System Preferences → Trackpad → More Gestures and changed

- Mission Control to ‘Swipe up with three fingers’, and
- App Exposé to ‘Swipe down with three fingers’.

Those gestures now worked with 3 fingers. Then I changed it back to ‘Swipe up/down with four fingers’ on both and they started working again using the four-finger gestures.

Comment: `killall Dock` has worked for me on 10.9.3 too

Answer (score 2):

This started happening to me on my early-2013 MacBook Pro since I upgraded to Mavericks.  It happens both and with and without the Magic Trackpad.

Based on the note at the end of Andrew's answer, I ran `killall Dock` from a Terminal window and the gestures started working again.

This [blog post](http://blog.creatingdrew.com/mac-os-x-gestures-freeze-or-stop-working-how-to-fix/) has more information about the issue and there is an [Alfred extension](http://software.creatingdrew.com/mac-gestures-not-working-or-frozen-alfred-extension/) to fix it too.

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was that dragging got turned off in Universal Access somehow.  Go to Settings -> Universal Access -> Mouse & Trackpad -> Trackpad Options and turn on Dragging if it's not enabled.